# Deadlock Enabling CDC on multiple tables at once

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a CICD process that can spawn jobs in parallel that create *different* databases with the same set of tables and enable cdc on each of their tables with sequential statements like this:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table  @source_schema = N'dbo', @source_name = N'table1', @role_name = NULL;
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table  @source_schema = N'dbo', @source_name = N'table2', @role_name = NULL;
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table  @source_schema = N'dbo', @source_name = N'table3', @role_name = NULL;
```

..etc

When there are more than one of these jobs running at once, they will often complain with the following error:

> Could not update the metadata that indicates table [dbo].[table1] is
>   enabled for Change Data Capture. The failure occurred when executing
>   the command '[sys].[sp_cdc_add_job] @job_type = N'capture''. The error
>   returned was 22836: 'Could not update the metadata for database
>   DatabaseForJob1 to indicate that a Change Data Capture job has
>   been added. The failure occurred when executing the command
>   'msdb.dbo.sp_add_job'. The error returned was 1205: 'Transaction
>   (Process ID 292) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process
>   and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.'.
>   Use the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and
>   resubmit the request.'. Use the action and error to determine the
>   cause of the failure and resubmit the request.

This seems to suggest that you can't enable CDC on tables with the same name in two different databases at the same time.  Is that true?  If not, what could be causing this issue and how is it addressed?  It only happens when there are more than one of these jobs running at once and I do see deadlock reports in the event_file.

Comment: "The failure occurred when executing the command '`msdb.dbo.sp_add_job`'" tells you CDC isn't *directly* at fault here and the names are a red herring. Enabling CDC for the first time requires the creation of a cleanup job, and apparently `sp_add_job` isn't safe to execute in parallel and deadlocks on internal shared resources in `msdb`. As a workaround, you could try using a `serializable` transaction (this has no guarantee of succeeding) or if that won't do it, use `sp_getapplock` to introduce a mutex so it's done for no more than one database at a time.

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer with an example of using sp_getapplock in this context I'll accept it.

Comment: Yet another option (to increase parallelism) could be to call [`sys.sp_cdc_add_job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-add-job-transact-sql) explicitly to create the capture and cleanup jobs manually before enabling CDC; after that, `sp_cdc_enable_table` should have no more need for creating jobs. Of course, these calls would also need to be serialized, but depending on how you're creating your databases that might be more natural. (I have no experience with this, however, so I don't know if it would work exactly the same.)

Comment: Actually, now that I'm thinking about it I don't know that `sp_getapplock` would work -- the problem is that almost everything in SQL Server is scoped to a database, but you specifically need to mutex things running *across* databases. That might be a little tricky! Creating tables in the system databases is icky. Some sort of wizardry with a global temp table perhaps.

Comment: I can't control when the different jobs that are executing these cdc enable commands in parallel are run.  They run on triggers outside of my control or the control of sql server.  Adding sys.sp_cdc_add_job to the scripts that these jobs would run would cause the same issue if they can't be run in parellel, no?